# Is there any way to change location of APFS local snapshots?

Tags: macos, apfs, ventura

I use APFS local snapshots to recover my Mac,
but I wonder if there is a possibility to change snapshot location from Mac built-in SSD to USB flash drive or external SSD?
[image: Disk Utility]

Comment: Making a snapshot flags data to not be overwritten on the volume. To change the location to another drive, you would instead have to copy the data or clone the volume, which in not the same thing as taking a snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, a snapshot is fundamentally a part of your disk's filing system. You could think of it as a second file catalogue, pointing to the same data as your main catalogue where the files are the same, and pointing to different data only where the files differ.

From your image, you've used c. 120 Gb of a 250 Gb volume, and your snapshot is 1 Gb. So you've got no worries about running out of space.

Comment: So if I want to move snapshots, I need to clone whole system?

Comment: @Alexander I'm saying there's neither point nor need to moving them.